# Android OAuth2 - Multiple API client projects, one app

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

**Scenario:**

Building an Android app which services multiple clients (they pick a company from a spinner on the login page).  Two of these clients use Google sign on in order to get a server access token, and they are in unique projects on the Google API Console.  The server access token is then used to return an account object from our servers to the app.

**Problem:**

I've created a web application oauth2 client id in each of these two client projects.  Passing this web application client ID using GoogleAuthUtil works fine IF there's an Android oauth2 credential in the same API project with an appropriate SHA1 key.  That's great, but I can't add another Android credential to the second project, it complains that the SHA1 key is already being used.

Since this will be published as a single app, with a single signing key, I can't figure out how I can overcome this issue.  Our iOS apps are using GIDSignin which allows you to pass a server client id and an app client id, and no SHA1 key drama, so it works fine there.  Of course I could use unique key stores for these two clients, but then we'd be releasing multiple apps.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have some problem. Did you resolve this?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? I am also searching for the same. Please help me if you have any solution.